# path between two nodes in a graph breadth first search

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph, breadth-first-search, undirected-graph

I am trying to write a python program that takes **input** as "**adjacency list (or dictionary)** to represent an undirected graph", "**source vertex**" and "**destination vertex**".

The program should use Breadth First Search and **output** **all possible paths from source to vertex within the given graph**.

Since this is an assignment where I just need to find all paths between a source and goal I used networkx to get the job done, but I want to be able to write it myself using BFS.

```
d = {'1': ['3', '4', '5'], '3': ['1', '4'], '4':['1','3'], '5':['1']}

g = nx.Graph(d)

for path in nx.all_simple_paths(g, source='5', target='4'):
    print(path)
```

I have had several failed attempts and am unable to find solution elsewhere. Any help, is appreciated. have a good day! thanks!

Comment: How about providing some source code you've tried and doesn't work?

Comment: sure, just edited.